# How to push an object into an array which is the value in a key/value pair in php

Tags: php, object, key-value, array-push

I have chosen a **`Key =>`** Value pair as my data structure where the Key is some text and the value is an array into which I will store objects.
Here is where I declare my **`Key =>`** Value (array)

```
$array = array(
  "key1" => array(),
  "key2" => array(),
  "key3" => array(),
);
```

I am trying to loop through and push a new object into the array, but I can't figure out how.

Something like:

```
While (...){
 ...
 $object = new obj();
 array_push($array['key1'], $object);
 ...
}
```

but with this I get the error

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array
```

Comment: The particular code that you've shown should work just like that.

Comment: Turns out that arrays cannot be the value in a key value pair. I have had to modify my data structure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you mean?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong, but after some research I determined that a Key cannot pair to an array. If it can, I could not figure out how to add objects to that array by indexing the Key.

Comment: You're basically saying that the code in your question is not representative of your actual code?

Comment: It was, but when it did not work, I changed it. perhaps I should delete this question? it doesn't seem popular, and was not solved. I kept it because SO warned me not to.

Comment: All the answers below do not answer the OPs question.  The answers below show how to loop through the parent array to add `key1 = (object)array(),key2=(object)array()`.  He wants to add objects to the array that is the VALUE of key1...and then key2.  When done, the new data would look like: `$array = {key1: [  { 'obj1-A' : 'objValue'},{ 'obj1-B': 'objValue'} ], key2: [ { 'obj2-A' : 'objValue'}, { 'obj2-B' : 'objValue'} ]  }`.  Thus we wants to push objects into the array that IS the value of key1...and key2.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
for($i=1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $array['key'.$i] = (object) array();
}
```

Does the object need any kind of properties??

**EDIT:**

Try this modification:

```
While (...){
 ...
 $object = new obj();
 $array['key1'] = $object;
 ...
}
```

Another possiblity??

```
While (...){
 ...
 $object = new obj();
 $array['key1'][] = $object;
 ...
}
```

Comment: So, I tried to simplify things for clarity, but I must have oversimplified. The array was already declared, I just need to push an object into it.

Comment: See if what I have in the edit is more what you mean